# Object Oriented Programming and Encapsulation C++

Tags: c++-cli, encapsulation, oop

Given the below sample class in C++, as you can see one can access all properties/methods for pic1 from the calling module.  But only can access to pic2 via those declaration under public.  Beside the just mentioned point, as a beginner to object oriented programming, I just wonder which method is preferred by the pro for real life implementation?

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System;

ref class myClass
{
    PictureBox^ pic2;
public:
    PictureBox^  pic1;
    void setPic2() {pic2 = gcnew PictureBox;}
    void addPic2ToControl(System::Windows::Forms::Form^ x) {x->Controls->Add(pic2);}
    void setPic2Image(String^ filePath) {pic2->Image = dynamic_cast<Image^>(gcnew Bitmap(filePath));}
    //more functions for to access pic2...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulation in C++ is usually accomplished by marking fields in your class as `private` or `protected`. However, you shouldn't rely on this totally as a way to keep stuff truly private per se-- if this is actually a security issue, for example, it won't help at all (remember `friend` functions.) It's more intended as a way to "divide-and-conquer" the program complexity and keep the code clean. This is an age-old challenge in computer programming, and encapsulation is just one of many valid techniques programmers have developed over the years.

How should encapsulation be used in your source code? Well a lot of people will insist, for example, that you should never have public *variables* in your classes, only public *methods*, and that public variables should be emulated using "getter/setter" functions. I don't necessarily agree with this, but I think it's fair to say that your classes should treat what it does as public information, and how it does it (and its internal state) as private information. This is just common sense anyway, even if you're not doing OOP. Among C programmers, a `static` (persistant) variable within a function is considered better practice than a variable with global scope if you can get away with it.

Comment: As of this moment, I got 3 answers.  And all three answers reinforced what I have learned and understood.  Since yours is the first.  I will marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

***What is Encapsulation?***
`Encapsulation` means binding the data and the methods that operate on that data in a single unit.

***How do you implement Encapsulation?***
By creating a `type` like `structure` or a `class`

Usually the data member variables inside a class are kept under `private` or `protected` access specifiers and the access to them is provided through `public` member functions. This guards honest mistakes of a programmer of accidentally modifying the member data if available publically. It provides a means of accessing and modifying the member data through explicit publically exposed function calls and hence more deliberate and less error prone.

Given the above, I believe, keeping `pic2` private and providing access to it through `member functions` seems to be the appropriate way

Comment: As of this moment, I got 3 answers.  And all three answers reinforced what I have learned and understood.

Comment: @user523234: Thats the best thing about SO. Lots of answers which help one learn new things :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the pros of restricting access to members through methods is that you now control the management of the variable at a central location (within the class itself). If later you decide to do some processing to pic2 before providing it to the caller you can do that in your access methods without the need to change it at multiple places

Later on if performance is a concern you can consider the option of inlining the methods

Comment: As of this moment, I got 3 answers.  And all three answers reinforced what I have learned and understood.